# Returning records "only first," and "all but first" in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to return the first created record, and all *but* the first created record, for all individual users given certain constraints. My SQL is broken, but I can't for the life of me figure out where/why.

## Object Model

I have 4 models of interest: User, Course, Question, and QuestionRecord.

Everytime a User answers a Question, a QuestionRecord is generated. QuestionRecord is a many-to-one with User, Course, and Question. (Is that cardinality correct? Each QuestionRecord has a foreign key to exactly one User, one Course, and one Question)

In Ruby:

```
class QuestionRecord < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :question
…
end
```

## Desired Outcome #1: First Record

What I'd like is to return the *first* question record for *each* user, given a course and a question. Put another way, if Jane, and Bill have answered the question twice, John hasn't attempted it, and Pete has answered it 7 times, I want 3 records returned, the first answer attempt, by creation date, from Jane, Bill, and Pete.

I could do this in the code, but want it in SQL for efficiency.

This is what I have:

```
SELECT qr.id 
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN question_records qr 
ON u.id = 
  (SELECT x.user_id 
   FROM question_records x 
   WHERE x.course_id = #{course.id} 
   AND x.question_id = #{question.id} 
   AND x.user_id = u.id 
   ORDER BY created_at ASC 
   LIMIT 1 )
```

This query just runs for 40 minutes or so, and doesn't actually return anything. I ran it with a subset of 50 records, and had the weird issue that all the returned qr.id results were "1"

## Desired Result #2: All **but** the first record

Now here, I want all records for all users **except** the first record. My thought was that, in essence, this is the same query, except that I want all records, and I want to offset the returned index by one:

```
SELECT qr.id 
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN question_records qr 
ON u.id = 
  (SELECT x.user_id 
   FROM question_records x 
   WHERE x.course_id = #{course.id} 
   AND x.question_id = #{question.id} 
   AND x.user_id = u.id 
   ORDER BY created_at ASC 
   OFFSET 1 )
```

However, it's obvious that if the first query doesn't work, the second won't.

## Coda

Does anyone have any guidance on this query? It'd be nice to have it as efficient as possible, so I could index question_records on [course_id, question_id] or whatever it takes. I'm also assuming that I'm missing a possibility to use "GROUP BY x.user_id", but wasn't sure how to add it without adding more gum in the works.

For the record, the database we're using is MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For #1, if your ID values are sequentially issued:

```
SELECT     MIN(qr.id) AS FirstQRID
FROM         users AS u INNER JOIN
                      question_records AS qr ON qr.user_id = u.id
WHERE     (qr.course_id = #{course.id}) AND (qr.question_id = #{questionid})
GROUP BY u.id
```

Then, for #2:

```
SELECT qr.id
FROM         questions AS qr2
WHERE      (qr2.course_id = #{course.id}) AND (qr2.question_id = #{questionid}) AND
           (NOT qr.id = (SELECT     MIN(qr.id) AS FirstQRID
                         FROM         users AS u INNER JOIN
                                               question_records AS qr ON qr.user_id = u.id
                         WHERE     (qr.course_id = qr2.course_id) AND (qr.question_id = qr2.quesion_id) AND
                                   (qr.user_id = qr2.user_id)))
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, this should be sufficient

```
SELECT qr.id, max(field_1), max(field_2), etc.
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN question_records qr 
ON u.id = qr.user_id
GROUP BY qr.id 
ORDER BY [the field that determines the first question]
```

For the second question, you have a few options.  1) Just do a select and toss the first one in the application layer. 2) Develop a query that returns arbitrary ranges

Option 2 is known as the top-n-per-group problem with the addition that you'll be limiting the range at both ends.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this, but should this be INNER JOIN question_records qr
ON u.id IN (SELECT x.user_id 
           FROM question_records x 
           WHERE x.course_id = 2233
           AND x.question_id = 20965) ? I need to subset that query for a specific course and question.

Comment: @JohnMetta - You don't need the nested query for this and I suspect that is, in part, why you have performance problems.  You can put `WHERE x.course_id = 2233 AND x.question_id = 209651` in the query above and get the same effect.  The join is between the keys of the two tables

Comment: Yeah, just saw that:

SELECT qr.*
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN question_records qr 
ON u.id = qr.user_id
WHERE qr.course_id = 2233
AND qr.question_id = 20965
GROUP BY qr.id 
ORDER BY qr.created_at

Works great– and fast. Thanks!